# How to Create a Configmap dynamically from a file

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I can create config map from a property file and use the same config files inside the POD. However, I don't want to use the configmap created in past and supplied with the helmchart. Rather in the helmchart values.yaml i want to provide a file name from where the config map will be created dynamically ..

Any suggestions/examples are welcome .

Thanks in advance -
Tutai

Answer (score 1):

See if the approach described in [kubernetes/charts issue 1310](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/1310) works for you.

> I suggest that we allow for overriding the name of the `ConfigMap` that gets mounted to the persistent volume.
>   That way, the parent chart could create, and even make templates for, these `ConfigMaps`.
>
> For example `values.yaml` could have the following fields added:

```
## alertmanager ConfigMap entries
##
alertmanagerFiles:
  # ConfigMap override where full-name is {{.Release.Name}}-{{.Values.alertmanagerFiles.configMapOverrideName}}
  configMapOverrideName: ""
...

## Prometheus server ConfigMap entries
##
serverFiles:
  # ConfigMap override where full-name is {{.Release.Name}}-{{.Values.serverFiles.configMapOverrideName}}
  configMapOverrideName: ""
...
```

You can see the implementation of that issue in [commit 2ea7764](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/commit/2ea776441e305cab858913e2c2806f5122df06dd), as an example of override.

---

This differs from a file approach, where you create a new config map and replace the old one:

```
kubectl create configmap asetting --from-file=afile \
        -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl replace -f -
```

See "[Updating Secrets and ConfigMaps](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-configmaps-and-secrets-68d061f7ab5b#33e4)" as an example.

Comment: Thanks for quick response VonC.. But as we are delivering the complete things using helm.. customer will not be allowed to run any "kubectl create"  command. Rather they want to supply the filename from where the configmap will be created during helm install. So can i pass any filename in values.yaml and the configmap inside templates directory will take the data part from the provided file name in the values.yaml ?

Comment: @TutaiDalal So the second approach is not a good fit. But the first might still work. I don't know Helm enough to know if you can add `.Values.xxx.configMapOverrideName` but the idea remains: have a `values.yaml` able to set values directly, or from an alternative source.